# Getting Maven resource exception

Tags: spring-boot, maven, spring-data-jpa, maven-plugin, maven-surefire-plugin

Could you please help me to overcome the issue:

Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:3.1.0:resources (default-resources) on project tight-core: Cannot create resource output directory:C:\TEJA

Comment: Looks like a window issue (based on the partial things I can see)... close all apps which are accessing the given directory ...

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Check write permission on `C:\` of Windows OS.